# Loop with twig using Symfony 4

Tags: loops, symfony, twig

I want to print categories on top of my loop results. I'm using twig, but categories which I want to print are displaying every time beside iterations.
I want to do it that way in order to spare some SQL request.

```
   {% for goodies in goodies %}                        
   {% if menus.bonbons == 'guimauve'%}
       <div class="col-lg-3">Title</div>
   {% endif %}
       <div class="col-lg-3">{{ iterations }}</div>}

   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Actually (logically) results are looking like this:

```
TITLE 
iteration
TITLE 
iteration
TITLE 
iteration
TITLE 
iteration
TITLE 
iteration
TITLE 
iteration
```

The result I want:

```
                         TITLE 
iteration
iteration
iteration
iteration
iteration
iteration
iteration
```

Note that I won't place title before loop because I only want those title for existing categories.

Comment: In fact, there should be only one `TITLE iteration` because of `{% if loop.first %}`

Comment: Note that `'guimove'` is actually spelled `'guimauve'`

Comment: Hello Cid, thanks for your support.

Comment: I cant use first because i have many categories ...

Comment: If only i could use 'if goodies.categorie in goodies'

Comment: Well, place `<div class="col-lg-3">Title</div>` before the loop ?

Comment: I cant do that because i want to print thoses titles only for existing categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finaly found a solution,

```
{% for goodies in goodies|filter(goodies => goodies.typeproduct == 'guimauve') -%}


    {% if loop.first %}
        <div class="col-lg-3  text-center mb-2">Title-Guimauve</div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if not loop.last %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">{{menus.goodiesname}}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">or</div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">{{menus.goodiesname}}</div>
    {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

i invite you to go there if you want some more details about |filter
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html

I hope it will help some of you !

Comment: Going by the output in your original example, I think the solution can simply be an if statement outside of a loop. If the iterable has items, then print the header, then print the iterable's items. With that you only print the header if the iterable is worth printing and you only print it once.